# how to retrieve password in django 2.0?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ldap3

Im using ldap for user authentication in django 2.0, and i need to create an endpoint to authenticate user from another application just passing the username to then redirect them. Isnt yet something to retrieve the raw password?

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9572182/5312750)?

Comment: How are you planning on passing the username? And they would be creating a password not retrieving a password correct?

Comment: Just an fyi, you generally don't retrieve a password, you supply a password and retrieve an ephemeral unique string / token. For instance, when a user authenticates to another application with Facebook they don't use a password.

Comment: ldap3 requires raw password, I've set the endpoint (url and view) to be receiving the username as a request parameter and at the view, then proceed query the User model using the username parameter to authenticate the user.

Comment: Is this only going to be happening once when the user registers? Or do you need the user to be able to login with this as well.

Comment: login with this as well, the registration is automatically set at the first login

Comment: Braden, do you have something to help me? -.-

Comment: Have you tried looking at how Facebook does this?https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login / https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

Comment: It is a nice security schema, but it is not what Im looking for or I need for this situation. This security layer could be in a future development phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `**encrypt**` method imported from `**django_cryptography.fields**`, define a password attribute for the model LdapProfile (model related to User to store the user profile on ldap) and then, use this password attribute in ldap.authenticate(username, password).

```
password = encrypt(models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    ))
```